# can't delete ARP entry with iproute2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, iproute, arp

On Ubuntu-14.04.5 I can't delete entry with `ip` tool from `iproute2` package.

```
% ip neigh show
10.0.0.119 dev eth2 lladdr c4:3d:c7:a2:fe:37 REACHABLE
fe80::2e0:ecff:fe36:2af6 dev eth2 lladdr 00:e0:ec:36:2a:f6 router REACHABLE
```

However deleting results in FAILED state of the entry:

```
% ip neigh del 10.0.0.119 lladdr c4:3d:c7:a2:fe:37 dev eth2
% ip neigh show
10.0.0.119 dev eth2  FAILED
fe80::2e0:ecff:fe36:2af6 dev eth2 lladdr 00:e0:ec:36:2a:f6 router REACHABLE
```

**UPDATE**

The same happens when I add an entry of the host, which is currently not turned on, the entry is added as `PERMANENT` and `ip neigh show` displays it but deleting fails, the entry is still displayed by `ip neigh show` but in state `FAILED`.

`iproute2` documentation says it is possible to delete. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is something actively trying to talk to 10.0.0.119 while you manipulate the table?

Comment: @Celada, I updated my post.

Comment: "iproute2 documentation says it is possible to delete" => can you quote it exactly please? Mine says that `delete` "**invalidates** a neighbour entry", which seems to be the case here.

Comment: @xhienne, http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-neighbour.8.html

Comment: What do you mean by _I can't delete entry_? What do you want to achieve? Remove an IP address from a NIC? Or what? Please edit your question to make this more precise.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem using kernel 4.19.

Setting the interface down then up solved it for me:

```
ifconfig eth2 down; ifconfig eth2 up
```

On an equipment being used by other people, this can break their network service though.